# Stuck with a MySQLdb SSL connection error in Python2.7

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, mysql-python

I have to maintain an old website built using Python2.7 that needs to continue working until we've finished creating a completely new version with more modern tools. Now this old website needs access to a remote MySQL database (connection is set up and working correctly), which so far has worked using the following:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=Host,user=User,passwd=Pass,db=DBse)
```

Now the server has been upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04. to Ubuntu 20.04., and while I managed to install `pip` and `MySQLdb` for Python2.7, I now get the following error for the lines above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number')
```

The SSL connection works fine in Python3 or directly from the command line.

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Locate and add the line skip_ssl in /etc/mysql/my.cnf ( have tried this on MySQL 8.0.29 , Ubuntu 18)

This was the only thing that worked for me.

[mysqld]

skip_ssl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).